# How to get resulting subprocess command string

Tags: python, subprocess

I have Python subprocess calls which are formatted as a sequence of arguments (like `subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'])` instead of a single string (i.e. `subprocess.Popen('ls -l')`).

When using sequenced arguments like I did, is there a way to get the resulting string that is sent to the shell (for debugging purposes)?

One simple approach would be to join all arguments together myself. But I doubt this would in all cases be identical to what subprocess does, since the main reason for using a sequence is to ['allow[s] the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments'](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

Comment: `subprocess` comes with a `list2cmdline` function that converts your list of arguments into a single string, taking care of whitespaces and quotes. Would it work for you ?

Comment: @Pierre: Yes, that is what I was looking for. I searched the subprocess doc page (the one I linked to), but unfortunately it doesn't mention it. If you put your suggestion in an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: On Unix/Linux, there is no such thing as a "resulting string that is sent to the shell". The arguments are sent separately. A string is only built on Windows.

Comment: @interjay: interesting, wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `subprocess` comes with (not documented in the docs pages) `list2cmdline` that transforms a list of arguments into a single string.
According to the source doc, `list2cmdline` is used mostly on Windows:

> On Windows: the Popen class uses CreateProcess() to execute the child
>   program, which operates on strings.  If args is a sequence, it will be
>   converted to a string using the list2cmdline method.  Please note that
>   not all MS Windows applications interpret the command line the same
>   way: The list2cmdline is designed for applications using the same
>   rules as the MS C runtime.

Nevertheless, it's quite usable on other OSes.

**EDIT**

Should you need the reverse operation (*ie*, splitting a command line into a list of properly tokenized arguments), you'll want to use the `shlex.split` function, as illustrated in the [doc of `subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).

```
>>> help(subprocess.list2cmdline)
Help on function list2cmdline in module subprocess:

list2cmdline(seq)
    Translate a sequence of arguments into a command line
    string, using the same rules as the MS C runtime:

    1) Arguments are delimited by white space, which is either a
       space or a tab.

    2) A string surrounded by double quotation marks is
       interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space
       contained within.  A quoted string can be embedded in an
       argument.

    3) A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash is
       interpreted as a literal double quotation mark.

    4) Backslashes are interpreted literally, unless they
       immediately precede a double quotation mark.

    5) If backslashes immediately precede a double quotation mark,
       every pair of backslashes is interpreted as a literal
       backslash.  If the number of backslashes is odd, the last
       backslash escapes the next double quotation mark as
       described in rule 3.
```

Comment: How is it "quite usable on other OSes" if quotations rules are completely different from POSIX?

Comment: That is a confusing way to put it, but the point is that you can run the function on any OS, even if the output is not directly usable. Useful for checking the output etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since Python 3.8, there's an [`shlex.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) function:

```py
>>> shlex.join(['ls', '-l'])
'ls -l'
```

Comment: And if you're below Python 3.8 but 3.3 and above, `shlex.join()` is just 
`' '.join(quote(arg) for arg in split_command)`