# How to Use or Execute Command CMD to use Xalan with Python Script/Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, xalan

I am doing a task as well as learning to program using Python 2.7 and Xalan XSLT processor.

The code:

```
    import wx, os
    from subprocess import call

    def OnImport(self, event):
    if self.Controler is not None and not self.CheckSaveBeforeClosing():
        return
    filepath = ""
    if self.Controler is not None:
        filepath = self.Controler.GetFilePath()
    if filepath != "":
        directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    else:
        directory = os.getcwd()


    #Choose Source File
    dialogIn = wx.FileDialog(self, _("Choose a model file"), directory, "",  _("model files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files|*.*"), wx.OPEN)
    if dialogIn.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        filepath = dialogIn.GetPath()
    else:
        return
    dialogIn.Destroy()


    #Choose Out XML Directory
    dirpath = ""
    dialogOut = wx.DirDialog (self,"Choose Out XML Directory","",wx.OPEN)
    if dialogOut.ShowModal () == wx.ID_OK:
        dirpath =  dialogOut.GetPath ()
        filepathplc = dirpath + "\plc.xml"

    # calling xalan via cmd
        call (['java', '-classpath', '"xalan.jar";"serializer.jar"', 'org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process', '-in', filepath, '-xsl', 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\XSL_Folder\debproj3.xsl', '-out', filepathplc, '/n'])
    else:
        return
    dialogOut.Destroy ()
```

I want to do xslt with xalan xslt processor with the calling xalan section but I get nothing. I want to write this command in cmd:

```
    java -classpath "xalan.jar";"serializer.jar" org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -in "source directory file" -xsl "xsl directory file" -out "output  target directory file"
```

Comment: assign the return value of your code to a variable and print it 
`x = call (['java',...`
`print(x)`
What does it show? Are you expecting terminal output? Then use `subprocess.check_output`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. When I tried to print the 'x = call (['java',... print(x)' it showed value of 1, and when the subprocess.check_output used it showed error 'returned non-zero exit status 1'. do you think my argument in subprocess module is wrong?

Comment: The 1 means there was an error. The arguments you are passing to `call()` should also work without Python. Have you tried that? Pleae try what is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130163/how-to-get-resulting-subprocess-command-string, get the resulting command line, print it and execute it on the console (cmd). Your command should be `subprocess.list2cmdline(['java', '-classpath', '"xalan.jar";"serializer.jar"', 'org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process', '-in', filepath, '-xsl', 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\XSL_Folder\debproj3.xsl', '-out', filepathplc, '/n']`).

Comment: Maybe the `/n` at the end is the problem, what should it do? Should it mean a newline? Then it is `\n`, but you don't need that, in case you want to simulate the return key being pressed,